# How to stop recycler view from recycling views?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a nested recycler view , which basically looks like a card view and a check list inside the card view , Now the issue i am facing is that when i close my app and reopen it .It starts displaying the list which is in the first card View to every other Card View inside my recycler View , to stop this i have used setIsRecyclable(false) inside my child adapter , but it isn't working and i keep facing the issue. How can i change my implementation ? I am using an observer to update my child adapter.

Code Inside my OnBindViewHolder for child adapter

```
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)

        holder.itemView.check_box_completed.isChecked = getItem(position).completed
        holder.itemView.text_view_name.text = getItem(position).name
        holder.itemView.text_view_name.paint.isStrikeThruText = getItem(position).completed

        Log.d("TAG1", "Inside: ${getItem(position)}")





        holder.itemView.check_box_completed.setOnCheckedChangeListener { checkBox, isChecked ->



                mainViewModel.updateListItem(
                    TaskList(
                        getItem(position).name,
                        isChecked,
                        getItem(position).Taskid,
                        getItem(position).taskNoteId
                    )
                )

            } else {

                mainViewModel.updateListItem(
                    TaskList(
                        getItem(position).name,
                        isChecked,
                        getItem(position).Taskid,
                        getItem(position).taskNoteId
                    )
                )

            }
        }
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Yeah sure , i have added the code

Comment: You appear to have asked [this question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65651684/10871073).